# Are 20 repetitions of Sycamore's one- and 2-qubit gates sufficient to produce a uniformly random state?

Tags: quantum-advantage, random-quantum-circuit, google-sycamore

In the answer to [this question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/4005/what-exactly-is-random-circuit-sampling/4006#4006) about random circuits, James Wootton states:

> One way to see how well we [fully explore the Hilbert space] is to focus on just randomly producing $n$ qubit states. These should be picked **uniformly from all possible states**, and not be biased towards the tiny set of states that it is easy for us to produce or write down. This can be done by running a random circuits of sufficient circuit depth. The number of gates for this thought to be efficient (i.e. polynomial in $n$), though I'm not sure if this is proven or is just a widely held conjecture. (Emphasis added).

The Google Sycamore team ran a cycle of $m=20$ repetitions of random single- and 2-qubit gates on $n=53$ qubits.

**Can there be a claim that Sycamore was able to prepare a state *drawn uniformly at random* from the Hilbert space of dimension $2^{53}$?**  That is, with the gate sets of Sycamore, are we getting far enough away from the $|000\cdots 0\rangle$ initial state to be uniformly random?

Certainly a simple counting argument is sufficient to show that there are *many* states in the Hilbert space that would never be achieved, or are even $\epsilon$-close to being acheived, by only $20$ repetitions of the Sycamore gate-set; however, can we say that the states that *could be* achieved by $20$ such repetitions are uniformly distributed within the Hilbert space?

I suspect the answer is most assuredly "yes", the Sycamore repetition is sufficient to uniformly explore the entirety of the Hilbert space, much as only $7$ dovetail shuffles are sufficient to randomly shuffle a deck of cards.  However, in the setting of a Hilbert space, can this conjecture be placed on any theoretical footing?

Note that I think this question is independent of the claim of *supremacy*.  Even if the circuit wasn't deep enough to fully and uniformly explore all corners of the Hilbert space, it may be difficult/impossible for a classical computer to compute any such state produced by Sycamore.

Comment: See [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.06957)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, you would need an astronomical circuit depth in order to get close to a uniformly random state, or even close to a randomly chosen probability distribution on the $2^{53}$ outputs.

As a first estimate, consider how many different distributions you need in order to be within 1/8 of the total variation distance of any distribution on $N$ outputs.   There is special formula that the TVD ball of radius $r$, in the space of these distributions, has volume $r^{N-1}\binom{2N-2}{N-1}$ times the volume of the entire simplex of distributions.    Recall also the elementary inequality $\binom{2N-2}{N-1} < 4^{N-1}$.   Therefore, to get within a TVD distance of $\frac18$ of even half of the space of measures on the simplex, you need at least $2^{N-2}$ examples.   Recall also that $N = 2^n$ is exponential in the number of qubits.  The result is a doubly exponential lower bound for the number of needed circuits.

On the other side, technically speaking there are infinitely many random circuits of any given depth, because a 2-qubit gate has continuous parameters.  However, there is some finite set of gates that comes close to all of the 2-qubit gates.  Skipping over some calculation, the end result is that unitary operators that you can make with circuits of depth $d$ acting on $n$ qubits is well-approximated by $2^{\mathrm{poly}(n,d)}$ distinct examples, which is only singly exponential with a polynomial exponent, rather than doubly exponential.

However, if circuits of any reasonable size don't produce a randomly chosen distribution, small circuits might still produce states or distributions with the same *features* as one that is actually randomly chosen.  For many natural types of features, such as the spectrum of probabilities of the individual outcomes, that is exactly what happens. The approximate $t$-design property is a related standard, and is much weaker than actually achieving a uniformly random distribution on outputs or anything close to it.

Comment: Is there an analogous with the [mixing of the 15 puzzle](https://www.quantamagazine.org/mathematicians-calculate-how-randomness-creeps-in-20191112/)?  It's straightforward to mix such puzzles so that any *particular tile* is uniformly distributed among the $16$ squares; however, it takes longer to scramble the puzzle such that all $16$ squares are in one of the $\frac 12\cdot 16!$ possible states.

Comment: Yes, that's right.  The effect is much stronger in a very large puzzle than a small one.  Google Sycamore is in analogous to a puzzle with 10 quadrillion pieces rather than just 16; but also the scrambling is much faster than just moving one piece at a time.