# Why is sampling considered difficult on a classical computer but easy on a quantum computer?

Tags: complexity-theory, classical-computing, fourier-sampling

It is my understanding that classical computers have a hard time sampling results from an output from a quantum circuit, but quantum computers find it very easy to do so. Why is this?

Comment: Your question is pretty broad right now, and it's not clear if you're asking why sampling can be hard classically, or why sampling can be easy on a QC.   Have you reviewed this [question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/4005/what-exactly-is-random-circuit-sampling), and do you have any specific follow-ups? Can you consider revising your question to be more focused, for example asking one particular area wherein you'd like more detail? Briefly, it almost always has to do with minus signs, and destructive interference, in quantum computers.